# What does it mean for dependencies to show inward?

Tags: clean-architecture

Let's say I have a use case (business logic), an adapter (database) and a domain object. I need to call the database from my domain logic, but the question is how. The way a do it right now is by giving the domain the adapter:

```
function usecase(adapter, domain):
     domain(adapter)

function domain(adapter):
    [some logic]...
    adapter.save_to_database()
    [more logic]...

call usecase(adapter, domain)
```

Now in order to avoid letting the domain logic know the adapter, I would need to return all data and call the adapter from the use case~

```
function usecase(adapter, domain):
     data = domain.some_logic()
     other_data = adapter.save_to_database(data)
     domain.more_logic(other_data)
```

So, every time I use an adapter, I need to exit the domain, in order to call the adapter. Is that correct? If, so why is it better than the solution above?

Comment: ummm... Having domain object calling IO doesnt make sense - you should have service do the calling (maybe with your domain object as parameter). Can you provide more information? (like, is your "class Domain" really domain object... :) )

Comment: or, let me rephrase - business logic (something do something else - like, something is writen to file) goes into use case, not in domain object. Is your "class Domain" strangely named use case? Then everything is ok (and you dont have problem with dependencies). It is (as the name suggests) domain object? Then you are doing it wrong - you should create/alter use-case to do what you want to (best using some service ;) ).

Comment: There is your problem: `domain.some_logic()` - domain object (for example `Car`) doesnt have any logic. I think you are mixing Clean Architecture with DDD. In Clean Architecture, Domain Object is more like "just an Entity" (with some get;set; properties storeable in database - really simple stuff here, plain ORM entity). You dont have `myCar.StartEngine()`, but you have `class StartEngineUseCase { ctor(CarStarterService carStarterServiceFromIoC); function Invoke(); }`.